# Datagrid grouping - how to get level of groupheader

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, grouping

I really need to know, on which level of grouping im standing ... knowing only if its bottom level or not is not enough

so I have this code

```
private void CustomDataGrid_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        var RowGroupHeader = (e.RowGroupHeader.DataContext as CollectionViewGroup);

        if (RowGroupHeader != null && RowGroupHeader.Items.Count > 0 )
        {
            // here i need to know the level
        }
    }
```

is there a way to get it?
Thx very much